# GCP destination group instances not being checked

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I'm trying to create a TCP/UDP load balancer on GCP to allow HA on my service, but I've noticed that when I create a destination group, all instances in that group are marked as unhealthy and are not being checked by google (I've seen the machine logs to check it). The firewall is open because is for testing purpose, so I'm sure that is not the problem.

I've created an HTTP/S load balancer using a backend with similar check configuration and the same machine is marked as healthy, so is not a problem of that machine (even now the logs shows how google is really checking that instance).

Both checks are HTTP to port 80, so I'm not able to see where's the problem and the difference between both kind of load balancers checkers.

Also I've checked to disable health check but the instance still marked as unhealthy and the traffic is not being sent to any of the instances, so the load balancer is not usefull it all.

Is necessary any other configuration to make it check the instance?

Thanks and greetings!!

Comment: Which exact kind of TCP/UDP load balancer did you use `TCP LB`, `TCP Proxy LB`, `SSL Proxy LB` or `UDP LB` ?

Comment: In Basic mode is just the second and third options (TCP load balancer and UDP load balancer). On Advanced mode is on Forwarding Rules (that are the only ways to create an UDP balancer for example). The problem is that google don't check the instance and then never is healthy. Using backend the instance is checked and look healthy, but only allows HTTP/S, TCP and SSL so is not usefull for UDP ports...

Answer (score 1):

### Creating a TCP load balancer

When you're using any of the Google Cloud load balancers, you need not expose your VM's external ports to the internet, only your load balancer needs to be able to reach it.

The [steps to create a TCP load balancer are described here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/network/example). I find it convenient to use `gcloud` and run the commands, but you can also use the Cloud Console UI to achieve the same result.

I tried the below steps and it works for me (you can easily modify this to make it work with UDP as well - remember you still need HTTP health checks even when using UDP load balancing):

```
# Create 2 new instances
gcloud compute instances create vm1 --zone us-central1-f
gcloud compute instances create vm2 --zone us-central1-f

# Make sure you have some service running on port 80 on these VMs after creation.

# Create an address resource to act as the frontend VIP.
gcloud compute addresses create net-lb-ip-1 --region us-central1

# Create a HTTP health check (by default uses port 80).
$ gcloud compute http-health-checks create hc-1

# Create a target pool associated with the health check you just created.
gcloud compute target-pools create tp-1 --region us-central1 --http-health-check hc-1

# Add the instances to the target pool
gcloud compute target-pools add-instances tp-1 --instances vm1,vm2 --instances-zone us-central1-f

# Create a forwarding rule associated with the frontend VIP address we created earlier
# which will forward the traffic to the target pool.
$ gcloud compute forwarding-rules create fr-1 --region us-central1 --ports 80 --address net-lb-ip-1 --target-pool tp-1

# Describe the forwarding rule
gcloud compute forwarding-rules describe fr-1 --region us-central1

IPAddress: 1.2.3.4
IPProtocol: TCP
creationTimestamp: '2017-07-19T10:11:12.345-07:00'
description: ''
id: '1234567890'
kind: compute#forwardingRule
loadBalancingScheme: EXTERNAL
name: fr-1
portRange: 80-80
region: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/PROJECT_NAME/regions/us-central1
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/PROJECT_NAME/regions/us-central1/forwardingRules/fr-1
target: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/PROJECT_NAME/regions/us-central1/targetPools/tp-1

# Check the health status of the target pool and verify that the
# target pool considers the backend instances to be healthy
$ gcloud compute target-pools get-health tp-1
---
healthStatus:
- healthState: HEALTHY
  instance: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/PROJECT_NAME/zones/us-central1-f/instances/vm1
  ipAddress: 1.2.3.4
kind: compute#targetPoolInstanceHealth
---
healthStatus:
- healthState: HEALTHY
  instance: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/PROJECT_NAME/zones/us-central1-f/instances/vm2
  ipAddress: 1.2.3.4
kind: compute#targetPoolInstanceHealth
```

### HTTP Health Checks are required for non-proxy TCP/UDP load balancers

If you're using a UDP load balancer (which is considered Network Load Balancing in Google CLoud), you will need to spin up a basic HTTP server which can respond to HTTP health checks in addition to your service which is listening on a UDP port for incoming traffic.

The same also applies to non-proxy based TCP load balancers (which is also considered Network Load balancing in Google Cloud).

This is [documented here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/network/#health_checking).

> [**Health checking**](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/network/#health_checking)
>
> Health checks ensure that Compute Engine forwards new connections only
>   to instances that are up and ready to receive them. Compute Engine
>   sends health check requests to each instance at the specified
>   frequency; once an instance exceeds its allowed number of health check
>   failures, it is no longer considered an eligible instance for
>   receiving new traffic. Existing connections will not be actively
>   terminated which allows instances to shut down gracefully and to close
>   TCP connections.
>
> The health check continues to query unhealthy instances, and returns
>   an instance to the pool once the specified number of successful checks
>   is met.
>
> Network load balancing relies on [legacy HTTP Health checks](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/health-checks#legacy_health_checks) for
>   determining instance health. Even if your service does not use HTTP,
>   you'll need to at least run a basic web server on each instance that
>   the health check system can query.

Comment: I'll try with commands instead web interface, but is strange because the instances are working fine (of course listening on port 80 too), and as I said, other health checks from google are really checking that machine and saying that is OK.

Comment: @DanielCarrascoMarín - Assuming your configured health check URL is `http://host:80`, can you run `curl http://VM1_IP:80` from both the same VM and a different VM? Also look at the output of the `gcloud compute target-pools get-health` command to see what the health checker of the Load Balancer thinks.

Comment: Thanks!!, I'll give a try. Anyway, other health checks detect it as healthy and the machine is serving a webpage that is accesible through the external IP, so I'm sure that the nginx server is working.